# date-format-picture-ends-before-converting-entire-input-string Open Query

Tags: sql, oracle, ssms

After a lot of R&D still not able to convert date in dd-Mon-YYYY format .am uisng open query from SSMS to oracle view but not able convert the date So reuesting you please help.

below are my query
select  * from openquery(oracle,'select  to_char(to_date("created date",''yyyy-mm-dd''),''dd-mon-yyyy'') from Oracle View')

Data is coming the the view in below format for date
2020-10-07 00:00:000

Comment: Edit your question and show examples of what the the value looks like *in the Oracle table*.  Also be clear on what you want it to look like in the query you are writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is in `'dd-Mon-YYYY'` format, then it is a string.  You can convert it to a date using:

```
select to_date(created_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

If you have a `date` in the remote table and you want to convert it to a string in this format, then use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(created_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: I assume you meant "If you have a `date` in the *remote* table"